# multiple merge operations on two dataframes using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes where multiple operations are to be implemented, for example:

**old_DF**

```
id   col1   col2    col3
-------------------------
1    aaa        
2           bbb     123
```

**new_DF**

```
id   col1   col2    col3
-------------------------
1           xxx      999
2    xxx    kkk
```

The following operations need to be performed on these dataframes:

1. Merging the two dataframes
2. Replacing only the blanks (NAs) cells in the old_DF with corresponding values from new_DF
3. Cells from both the dataframes where the values are contradicting should be reported in a new dataframe

**Desired results:**

updated_df

```
id   col1   col2    col3
-------------------------
1    aaa    xxx     999
2    xxx    bbb     123
```

conflicts_df

```
id   col1   col2    col3
-------------------------
2           bbb
2           kkk
```

I can use `.append()` method to join the two dataframes and I guess one can use `.bfil()` or `.ffil()` methods to fill in the missing values. But I am unsuccessful with both `.bfil()` and `.ffil()`. I have tried `df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates()` but I do not get the desired results. Additionally, I do not understand how to perform step 3 mentioned above. Is there anyone who can help with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting up:

```
old_df = pd.DataFrame([
  [1, 'aaa', pd.NA, pd.NA],
  [2, pd.NA, 'bbb', 123]],
  columns=['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
new_df = pd.DataFrame([
  [1, pd.NA, 'xxx', 999],
  [2, 'xxx', 'kkk', pd.NA]],
  columns=['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Use combine_first to get the `updated_df`, setting `id` as the index

```
old_df = old_df.set_index('id')
new_df = new_df.set_index('id')
updated_df = old_df.combine_first(new_df)

# updated_df outputs:
# (reset the id if necessary)
   col1 col2 col3
id               
1   aaa  xxx  999
2   xxx  bbb  123
```

generate a dataframe of `masks` using boolean logic, checking that both the old & new frames have values in a given cell & that the values differ, and pick cells from both old & new using the mask where any row in the mask is True

```
mask = pd.notnull(new_df) & ~old_df.eq(new_df) & pd.notnull(old_df)
conflicts_df = pd.concat([old_df[mask], new_df[mask]]).dropna(how='all')

# conflicts_df outputs
   col1 col2 col3
id               
2   NaN  bbb  NaN
2   NaN  kkk  NaN
```

Comment: It does not work for me. When I run the first part, I get the output dataframe similar to old_df. In the second part, I replaced updated_df.eq(new_df) wtih old_df.eq(new_df) and that worked. However, there are two problems: 1) I must have id column as index which i want to avoid as i can have multiple id columns, 2) the dataframes must be of equal sizes, and in several cases I have variable length dataframes. It will be best if i can keep the id column as it is and use it as a "key".... 

Is there any other way then making setting the index to 'id' that can work?

Comment: `I get the output dataframe similar to old_df`. without seeing your actual data, I would guess this is due you having `''` instead of `nulls` in your dataframes. `combine_first` takes the first `non-null` value. for the other issues, i would recommend updating your question with a representative dataset, because the sample you provided suggested equal length dataframes. Setting `id` as the index seems to me to be the natural way to do this, and i'm don't see any information being lost if it set as the index for the transformation. you can always `reset_index`, when you need `id` as a column

Comment: fixed answer (replaced `updated_df`  with `old_df` where you pointed out the error) and see updated answer on how I set up the old & new dfs. With this set up you should also see the same behavior as documented in the answer

Comment: this solution works for the problem stated. I will modify my question as a new question so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: I have posted another question with the same problem as an extension to this question. Perhaps you can contribute there too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622721/multiple-operations-on-two-dataframes-using-pandas